# Как в MS Server 2008 сделать автоподбор ID?

Tags: sql-server, база-данных

Как сделать, чтобы при ручном добавлении нового пользователя в БД на MS Server 2008, ID присваивался сам и автоматически? А то я сейчас создал программу, но там ID пишу я вручную. Но это не удовлетворяет меня.

**UPDATE (!)**
Я нашел, как это сделать. Там есть "Шаг Приращений", но там стоит значение false и она бесцветная, в свойствах. Т.е не могу ни этот false сделать true, ни др значения менять! Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

В свойствах колонки выберите: (Идентификатор) - да. По желанию установите начальное значение и шаг

[image]

Comment: @renegator дело в том, что в свойства захожу, а там все прозрачно. Ничего не могу менять!(

Comment: в категории "Спецификация идентификатора" есть 3 свойства. Первое из них устанавливает, является ли поле идентификатором. по умалочанию там стоит "нет". переключите в "да" тогда и остальные свойства станут доступными для редактирования

Comment: При создании новой таблицы, ставлю: Разрешить Значения NULL - ДА, Уникальный - ДА, Первичный Ключ - ДА! Больше там ничего при создании не предлагается. Делаю так, и ничего менять не могу @renegator

Comment: @iranda не получается! Невозможно менять их. Они прозрачные. Менять не получается их